# Dictonary to lowest instance

Tags: python, dictionary, instance

I have following classes:

```
from classes.partClass import Part 
from classes.linkClass import Link  

class Assembly: 
    def addPart(self, inputLine, objectTable): 
        self.partTable.append(Part(inputLine, objectTable))
      
    def addLink(self, inputLine):
         self.linkTable.append(Link(inputLine))

      def readAttributes(self, inputLine, length):
         inputLine = inputLine.strip() 
        inputLine = inputLine[length:].split('"') 
        for i in range(len(inputLine)): 
            if inputLine[i] != "":
                 if inputLine[i][-1] == "=":
                     if inputLine[i][:-1].strip() == "size_x":
                         self.sizeX = int(inputLine[i+1])
                     elif inputLine[i][:-1].strip() == "size_y":
                         self.sizeY = int(inputLine[i+1]) 
                     else:
                         print("Error")

      def __init__(self, inputLine, length):
         self.readAttributes(inputLine, length)
         self.partTable = []
         self.linkTable = []
```

```
from classes.valueClass import Value 
from classes.markupClass import Markup  

class Part: 
     def addValue(self, inputLine):
         self.Values.append(Value(inputLine))

      def addMarkup(self, inputLine):
         self.Markup.append(Markup(inputLine))

      def readAttributes(self, inputLine, objectTable):
         inputLine = inputLine.strip() 
        inputLine = inputLine[5:].split('"') 
        for i in range(len(inputLine)):
             if inputLine[i] != "":
                 if inputLine[i][-1] == "=":
                     if inputLine[i][:-1].strip() == "center_x":
                         self.centerX = int(inputLine[i+1])
                     elif inputLine[i][:-1].strip() == "center_y":
                         self.centerY = int(inputLine[i+1])
                     elif inputLine[i][:-1].strip() == "id":
                         self.id = int(inputLine[i+1][1:]) 
                     else:
                         print("Error")

      def __init__(self, inputLine, objectTable):
         self.Values = [] 
        self.Markup = []
         self.readAttributes(inputLine, objectTable)
```

If I create instances of theses classes:

```
assemblyTable = []
objectTable = [Object[0], Object[1]]
a = "Enter individual string from file"

for i in range(2):
    assemblyTable.append(Assembly(a, 5))
    a = inputFile.readline()
    
    for j in range(2):
        assemblyTable[-1].addPart(a, objectTable)
        a = inputFile.readline()

    for k in range(5):
        assemblyTable[-1].partTable[-1].addValue(a) 
        a = inputFile.readline()
```

I now want to read a dictionary of an "Assembly" instance with assemblyTable[0]._ _ dict _ _ and I get an output

```
{'sizeX': 3620, 'sizeY': 3220, 'zoom': 0.8, 'partTable': [<classes.partClass.Part object at 0x000001485A3B5E80>, <classes.partClass.Part object at 0x000001485A3B5EB0>, <classes.partClass.Part object at 0x000001485A3B5EE0>, 'linkTable': }
```

Is there a way to read the dictionary of the Subclasses Part and Link within the output of the assemblyTable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I tried to create an own _ _ dict _ _ method in every class and tried to return every existing attribute, but this seemed too laborious to me. Using vars() or dir() isn't returning the required output. I rather have to search through every single item of the output to get to my desired result. Therefore my _ _ dict _ _ method approach seems to be more convenient.